# Retrofit2 null content response body with response code = 200

Tags: android, rest, neo4j, retrofit2

I'm trying to send a request to Neo4j server using Retrofit2.

The service interface looks like this:

```
public interface PhoneBookContactAPI {
    @Headers({
        "Authorization: Basic XXXXXX",
        "Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @GET("/db/data/label/{label}/nodes")
    Call<List<PhonebookContact>> getContacts(@Path("label") String label);
}
```

When I call the service:

```
Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Globals.BASE_CLIENT_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

PhonebookContactAPI service = client.create(PhonebookContactAPI.class);

Call<List<PhonebookContact>> call = service.getContacts("PhoneBook");
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<PhonebookContact>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<PhonebookContact>> call, Response<List<PhonebookContact>> response) {

        Log.d("Call request", call.request().toString());
        Log.d("Response raw", String.valueOf(response.raw().body()));
        Log.d("Response code", String.valueOf(response.code()));

        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d("Response body", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
        }

        else  {
            Log.d("Response errorBody", String.valueOf(response.errorBody()));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<PhonebookContact>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
    }
});
```

I recieve this stack trace:

```
05-15 18:51:58.777 D/Call request: Request{method=GET, url=http://myneo4jserver.com/db/data/label/PhoneBook/nodes, tag=null}
05-15 18:51:58.777 D/Response raw: retrofit2.OkHttpCall$NoContentResponseBody@aec27d4
05-15 18:51:58.777 D/Response code: 200
05-15 18:51:58.791 D/Response body: [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

As you can see the body contains the right number of items but they are all empty.

What is wrong?

Comment: hit your url to browser and verify what response returned

Comment: Or use a client (plugin) to test out your request

Comment: or you can use postman plugin on chrome and then hit the same request on postman and verify your result

Comment: I tried to follow the same call with REST Client for Firefox and the server response is correct

Comment: Hey there, can you post your PhonebookContact class. I need to check it because i had similar problem